# How to bring a multiple volume LVM back to one volume due to a failing drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

Being new to hosting servers, I previously thought it'd be a good idea to create a logical volume using two hard drives, a 640GB hard drive and a 320GB hard drive. The 320GB hard drive is now failing due to age (5 years constant power on time, old Samsung HDD), and I would really like to bring back the data all to one disk.

The current volume I have is 900GB and only 17% of that is used. I used Ubuntu LiveCD to diagnose the PC and despite S.M.A.R.T. not reporting any issues with the disk, I'm certain that the drive is failing as it's gotten my system to freeze up a couple of times and it makes a lot of weird noises.

Now, I can't seem to find any resources on how to bring back the volume to one disk, if this is even possible at all. In case this isn't possible, I'd like some recommendations on how to recover the data from both disks, so I can format both and from then on not create a volume shared over two different drives.